# My calendar not allowing me to right click on it to find xpath of year and month

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to select any month or year from my date-picker but it is not allowing to right to click on it to find locater.
Also my datePicker not have css or table to iterate through months and year.

My application is built in react.

[image]